# SpeechSynthesisUtterance detect onend when only speaking completes once not on cancel

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, webapi, speech-synthesis

I am using `window.SpeechSynthesisUtterance` API and I found out when you call `window.speechSynthesis.cancel()` it immediately also calls `onend` event.
I want to do something specific only when the speaking ends but not when the utterance is canceled while it is being spoken.

How do I detect if speaking ended due to a cancel method call?

The `onend` event gives and event object:
`onend = event => { }`

But in both cases when the speech ends or is canceled the `event.type` is `'end'`.

Comment: For more context, I want to change a button's text to 'listen again' from 'mute' once the speaking ends but not when it is canceled (say on modal close).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [`charIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisEvent/charIndex) of the `SpeechSynthesisEvent` in an [`end`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/end_event) listener and compare it to the length of [`SpeechSynthesisEvent.utterance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisEvent/utterance).

For example,

```js
utterance.addEventListener('end', (evt) => {
  const { charIndex, utterance } = evt

  if (charIndex + 1 === utterance.text.length) {
    // End fired when utterance finished
  } else {
    // End fired before utterance finished
  }
})
```